# How can I tell if a name is meant to be masculine?

Tags: names

Would Kōsui be considered a male’s name?

Comment: 香水 means "cologne" or "perfume".  So I guess it could be either.  

Comment: My guess is that, generally, you can't. Especially being Japanese a gender neutral language. I suppose one could only speculate by guessing the kanji that would be used to write that name, but can't be more than a guess. Moreover, there are a lot of Japanese names that can be used both for males and females.

Comment: Kosui (幸水?, 高翠?, ...) is geneder-neutral, but it sounds to me like a rare stage/pen name of a rakugo performer, a haiku poet, etc. Do you have kanji? And how did you come up with this name?

Answer (score 2):

Names in Japanese are considered to be male or female mainly by tradition and customs, there isn't a rule that dictates that. But you can "guess" based on what usually happens regarding a name being masculine or feminine.

Masculine names usually finish with hiko(彦), rou(郎), o(男,夫,雄), to(人,斗),  ta(太) or suke(助,介).

Female ones with ko(子), (美), 奈(na) and 代(yo).

Also, if a name has more than 4 syllables it's most probably a masculine name.

Lastly, usually a name gives an image of "something" that can be interpreted as either masculine or feminine. Kousui (perfume), for example, doesn't have it's gender specified, meaning it can be both masculine or feminine, but is most probably going to be interpreted as a feminine name because of it's meaning; though that is not a rule.

You can search for the name and see if it is feminine, masculine or not specified, as for example in [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/kousui%20%23names) .

Comment: I am not sure why you were downvoted, but I have two comments: 1. Kousui only means perfume if it is spelt 香水, for any other combination of kanji it would not mean perfume. 2. The meaning of a Japanese name will always depend on how it is written (as in whether or not it contains Kanji, and what kanji these are) and there are many different conventions that I do not dare try to summarize. The common endings you mentioned above work as a good rule of thumb. 3. I am not sure if names are really interpreted as female/male based on their meaning in that way, Japanese is a genderless language